Does H7657, mean just "70"; or can it mean "60"also?
The primary rendering of H7657, is 70, but it is translated  just "threescore", without the "and ten" meaning  60 (Kjv); in Num. 31:33, 38; does anyone know why? Does the meaning of this word in Hebrew allow for this, or did the translators have a reason for the specific rendering of threescore, meaning 60?

The OP's assertion is simply untrue - the word שִׁבְעִים (shibim) means 70 (seventy) and is thus translated in BOTH Num 31:33, 38 in every translation I checked such as NIV, ESV, BSB, NASB.
Even in the KJV, which uses an awkward translation that is not literal, it still means "seventy".  Here is my literal translation of Num 31;33, 38

V33: And cattle two and seventy thousand
V38: And the cattle six and thirty thousand and tribute for YHWH two
and seventy

The "problem" with the OP's question appears to be the unfortunate phrasing chosen by the KJV which reads:

V33: And threescore and twelve thousand beeves,
V38: And the beeves were thirty and six thousand; of which the LORD'S
tribute was threescore and twelve.

Note that the KJV inexplicably translates "seventy-two" in each case as "three-score and twelve".  Thus, the number is correct but the translation is confusing.
The NKJV has corrected this anomaly.

"inexplicably translates "seventy-two" in each case as "three-score and twelve"".
— Perhaps they were influenced by the French counting system, which doesn't have specific names for seventy, eighty, or ninety.  69, 70, 71, 72, …, 79, 80, 81, …, 90, 91 are (in English words):
sixty-nine, sixty-ten, sixty-eleven, sixty-twelve, …, sixty-nineteen, four-score, four-score-one, …, four-score-ten, four-score-eleven.

@RayButterworth - good comment!  The odd things is that KJV uses "seventy" in other places such as Gen 4:24, 5:12, 31, 12:4, etc, etc.

Do you know if there is a peticular construction of this word, where it maintains the rendering of threescore.., also in rev.13.8, the translators chose to rendering the middle letter, as three score. Any connection with that letter in the septuigent, in the translations of threescore and ten in the o.t, instead of seventy, ?

@ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory - there is nothing special about "70" in this instance.   The translation is an inexplicable quirk of the KJV.
